# How to use data annotations for drop-down lists?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, user-interface, razor

In MVC3 data annotations can be used to speed up the UI development and validations; ie.

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New password")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }
```

However, if for a mobile app, there is no field label, only a drop-down list populated from the database.  How would I define this in this way?

```
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.[SOME LIST TYPE???])]
    [Display(Name = "")]
    public string Continent { get; set; }
```

Is it better not to use this method for this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well, I was trying to use the data annotations method for validation, etc.  Simply a regular dropdown that is populated from the db, where if no value is selected the error message is displayed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your ViewModel like this

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
   //Other Properties

   [Required]
   [Display(Name = "Continent")]
   public string SelectedContinent { set; get; }
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Continents{ set; get; }

}
```

and in your `GET` Action method, Set the Get the Data from your DB and set the Continents Collection property of your ViewModel

```
public ActionResult DoThatStep()
{
  var vm=new RegisterViewModel();
  //The below code is hardcoded for demo. you may replace with DB data.
  vm.Continents= new[]
  {
    new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Prodcer A" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Prodcer B" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Prodcer C" }
  }; 
  return View(vm);
}
```

and in your `View` (`DoThatStep.cshtml`) use this

```
@model RegisterViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.ValidationSummary()

  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedContinent, 
               new SelectList(Model.Continents, "Value", "Text"), "Select")

   <input type="submit" />
}
```

Now this will make your DropDown Required field.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to enforce the selection of an element in the DropDown use the `[Required]` attribute on the field you are binding to:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "")]
    public string Continent { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Continents { get; set; }
}
```

and in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.Continent, 
    Model.Continents, 
    "-- Select a continent --"
)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Continent)
```

Comment: If the dropdown does have a label defined (name ="some label"), is there a way to have it displayed above instead of beside?

Comment: Sure, just use the `@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Continent)` and then decorate your Continent property with the Display attribute: `[Display(Name = "some label")]`.