# dropdownlist validation in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to apply validation on dropdown list, i found some ways on google but unable to find best way to achieve in MVC 4.

I have dropdown list as below:

```
   <tr class="alignLeft">
    <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Form)</td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Form, new SelectList(Model.Form as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "SID", "SName", Model.Form),
          "< Select Form >"
        , new { style = "width:154px;" })
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Can any one share me, is there any annotation which should allow me to ensure, selected index is great then 0.
or any other appraoch ?

I am using .NET FRAMEWORK 4.5 and MVC 4.

thank You

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011804/how-to-use-data-annotations-for-drop-down-lists

Comment: Can we achive without taking additional property ?

Comment: If you want a valid value to always be selected, then just remove the optional label "< Select Form >".

Comment: i need that option too. Now i have implemneted as u posted ur first comment link. please add as separate comment, i will mark the answer. Thanks.