# EntityFramework Not Happy with System.Web.Mvc.SelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, poco

I'm building POCO classes for code-first EF to use in my ASP.NET MVC project. I'm trying to make a dropdown list for one of the fields based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12011942/594977), but EF was threw an error when trying to add the migration.

**Update:** Removed SelectListItems from the POCO, but still same EF error.

Relevant snippet of the POCO:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class Organization
{
    [DisplayName("Bank Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bank Name is required.")]
    public string AccountBank { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Banks { get; set; }
}
```

EF Error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: You normally wouldn't want to store SelectListItem entities in your database.  Instead you should have a Bank entity, and create SelectListItems only in the UI.

Comment: Why are you adding View logic into EF POCOs??

Comment: A `SelectListItem` is for UI.  It should not be stored in your database and should not be in your POCO.  Your database (= data model = business model) should store business objects.  The UI (view and/or controller) should convert the business objects to a format that can be used by your view, ie the selectlistitems.

Comment: Notice the use of a ViewModel in the linked answer you provided.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft and others, I removed SelectListItems from the POCO, but still same EF error.

Comment: They were telling you to remove it because it was a huge architecture mistake, not because it was causing the error. That error is not even an EF error. See my answer below for the explicit cause of your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs when the assembly for System.web.mvc that you included in your project does not match the version number you have explicitly defined in your config file. Go make sure the versions match.

Also, are you just trying to get the bank name via a drop down list in the view? If you are then you are adding unneeded complexity to your model by making the select list part of your model. You would be better off just loading that list into the viewbag and setting the selected value of it and o your model property.